# Modify animate function with JQuery

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-animate

I have the below function that works a treat, but instead of clicking the **#featured li.block div** to make the div spin; how would one make a link with a class button **a.button**? clickable to make the **#featured li.block div** divs spin?

```
$('#featured li.block div').click(function()
{
    var f = function($this, count) 
    {
        $this.animate({
            top: "-=200"
        }, 70, function() {
            $this.css('top', '220px').animate({
                top: "-=220"
            }, 70, function() {
                if (count > 0) {
                    count = count - 1;
                    f($this, count);

                    /*if(count == 0) {
                        if ($this.hasClass('showing')) {
                            $this.removeClass('showing').addClass('hiding').hide();
                        }
                    }*/
                }
            });
        });
    };
    f($(this), 8);
});
```

Comment: When you start your post with a greeting it pushes useful information out of the summary that appears on the questions page.  We typically prefer information over pleasantries.

Comment: Ok, just thought I'd say hello, never mind though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `a.button` as the selector for the click handler and the original selector for the function invocation.

**EDIT** I couldn't get your code to work regardless of the selector with more than one inner DIV.  Try this (bonus, it's simpler):

```
$('a.button').click(function()
{
    var f = function($this, count) 
    {
        $this.animate({
            top: "-=200"
        }, 70, function() {
            $this.css('top', '220px').animate({
                top: "-=220"
            }, 70, function() {
                if (count > 0) {
                    f($this, --count);
                }
            });
        });
    };
    $('#featured li.block div').each( function(i) {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout( function() {
               f( $this, 8 );
        }, i*100 ); // the ith div will start in i*100ms
    });
});
```

Comment: @Keith - thought you wanted to change the trigger element, you can just add the new selector to the old one as I've shown.  Make sure you update the line of code at the end of the handler as well otherwise it won't be applying the animation to the right element.

Comment: Wow, works a treat, the div doesn't go all the way down, but I think I can change this. Also, sorry for the additional 2 questions. 1.) Say I have 2 divs: 

    <li class="block">
        <div>aaa</div>
        <div>aaa</div>
    </li>

how, would I swap them on each click?

Comment: @Keith - got your rolling thing working again after a couple of tweaks.  I've updated and you can find it at http://jsfiddle.net/mx7Zh/.  Not sure what you mean by swap, you mean toggle their visibility?  Assuming one starts visible and the other not, just do `$('...li.block div').toggle();`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time TV, you have saved me hours!!

Comment: Ok,I'm getting greedy now, I apologize :) Can this code be run with a slight delay between those divs? So, number one div goes, then a milliseconds later, number 2 and so on?

Comment: @Keith, you mean start them at different times.  Should just be a small adjustment to use a different timeout for each one, I'll update.

Comment: @Keith - had to make one minor correction to capture `$(this)` for the setTimeout function.  Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nku7T/

Comment: Absolutely perfect!! I can't thank you enough. If you ever need some help with UI/design please email me